# on dropdown select value show hidden input field

Tags: javascript, html

This has definitely been covered before and im sure it will again but none of the examples ive found are helping me.

I have a dropdown field, when option 2(Admin) is selected i want to display a text input type that is otherwise hidden.

```js
const ac = document.getElementById("admin_code");
ac.style.display = "none";

function toggleDropdown(selObj){
  ac.style.display = selObj.value === "Admin" ? "block" : "none";
}
```

```html
<label>User Type:</label> <select id="userType" name="userType" id="userType" onchange='toggleDropdown(this);' required>
<option value="" selected>Select User Type</option>
<option value="Client">Client</option>
<option value="Admin">Admin</option>
<option value="Staff">Staff</option>
</select>
<br>
<div id="admin_code">
<label>Person Code:</label> <input type="text" name="adminCode" 
id="adminCode" placeholder="000001">
</div>
```

Currently when i go into the page with this on my admin_code div shows from the start. I have tried changing the style.display values both to none to see if it is even being called but it seems it is not.

Comment: Hi :) well, you are not passing any parameters during onchange event, you cannot handle the value in the function in that way. Youtr onchange event need to be like: onchange="toggleDropdown(this.value)". Otherwise your if condition will arrive alway over the second statment. I hope it can help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `this` keyword into your callback function:

```js
const ac = document.getElementById("admin_code");
ac.style.display = "none";

function toggleDropdown(selObj) {
  ac.style.display = selObj.value === "Admin" ? "block" : "none";
}
```

```html
<label>User Type:</label>
<select id="userType" name="userType" id="userType" onchange='toggleDropdown(this);' required>
  <option value="" selected>Select User Type</option>
  <option value="Client">Client</option>
  <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
  <option value="Staff">Staff</option>
</select>
<br>
<div id="admin_code">
  <label>Admin Code:</label> <input type="text" name="adminCode" id="adminCode">
</div>
```

Comment: While i can see this working in the snippet its not working in my code. the admin code is still constantly showing. when inspecting the div it shows element.style {}

Comment: @a.smith My guess is either `ac` isn't grabbing the right element, or you're forgetting to set `ac.style.display = "none";`

Comment: caching was the problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  First I set the initial style for div#admin_code to "display: none;"

Then I changed your function slightly

```js
    function toggleDropdown(){
    let value = document.querySelector('select').value;
      if (value=="Admin") {
         document.getElementById("admin_code").style.display = "block";
      } else {
          document.getElementById("admin_code").style.display = "none";
     }
    }
```

```html
    <label>User Type:</label> <select id="userType" name="userType" id="userType" onchange='toggleDropdown();' required>
                <option value="" selected>Select User Type</option>
                <option value="Client">Client</option>
                <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
                <option value="Staff">Staff</option>
    </select>
    <br><div id="admin_code" style="display: none;">
    <label>Admin Code:</label> <input type="text" name="adminCode" id="adminCode" >
    </div>
```